# Trying to use Java Http URL connection to do curl command

Tags: java, http, curl

Hi I have the following curl script

```
curl -i -X PUT -d "{\"loginList\":[{\"externalLoginKey\":\"1406560803453iGBoMm\",\"testStatus\":\"R\"}]}" -H "X-test-debug-override: true" -k  http://someapi/logins
```

I am trying to do a Http post using java. Following is my code. Am i doing something wrong? I  am getting error but curl runs fine

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpTesting {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String apiURL = "http://someapi/logins";
    URL url = new URL(apiURL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String str = "{\"loginList\":[{\"externalLoginKey\":\"1406565099034jZrHXe\",\"testStatus\":\"R\"}]}";
    con.disconnect();

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("X-test-debug-override", "true");
    con.connect();

    OutputStream outStream = con.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outStream);
    out.writeBytes(str);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);

}

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  If you are getting an exception, please include the full stack trace in your question.  Also, you probably should not call `con.disconnect()` on an HttpURLConnection you are about to use.

Comment: @VGR I am getting a 400 (Bad request)

Comment: did you put accept header in curl request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> -d, --data <data>
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server **using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.** Compare to -F, --form.

(Emphasis mine.)

Even though you are sending JSON, your Content-Type needs to be `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.  Which means you also need to encode your data using [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
out.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8"));
```

By the way, your `curl` command uses the PUT method while your Java code uses the `"POST"` method.